# connection already closed - psycopg2 - python

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7

Estoy realizando una migracion de datos de SQL Server a PGSQL con python.

Al momento de realizar las inserciones a PGSQL, luego de insertar aprox 10k o 20k registros, me arroja el siguiente error:
Connection already closed.

Este es el codigo que ejecuto para las inserciones a diferentes tablas.

```
try:
    #Insertar Usuarios                               
    cursor_pg = connection.cursor()
    cursor_pg.execute("query")
    user_id = cursor_pg.fetchone()[0]
except Exception as e:
    print("error de user"+str(e))
```

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente en algún punto del ciclo que inserta la sesión se esta perdiendo, lo que puedes hacer es recuperar una nueva conexión y retornarla dentro del manejo de la excepción.

```
for query in queries:
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
    except Exception as e:
        print e.message
        conn = psycopg2.connect(....)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Si quieres ser mas acertivo con el manejo de la excepción lo que puedes hacer es colocar en el exception el tipo:

```
except psycopg2.InterfaceError as e:
```

Con lo que puedes establecer una diferenciación de la excepciones que manejas, por ejemplo:

```
for query in queries:
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
    except psycopg2.ProgrammingError as exc:
        print exc.message
        conn.rollback()
    except psycopg2.InterfaceError as exc:
        print exc.message
        conn = psycopg2.connect(....)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos!

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651586/psycopg2-cursor-already-closed